# how to display data from MySql db to html pages in python

Tags: html, python-2.7

i want to display all the data in my table to a webpage using python when i click a button. here is my app.py code can anyone help me to finish this please..

```
def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="a", newname="s", number="d")
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="testdb")
        x = conn.cursor()
        x.execute("SELECT * FROM details")
        conn.commit()
        items = cursor.fetchall()
        return items()
        conn.rollback()
        conn.close()
        return render.index()
```

i want to display it on index.html.and table has 3 colums

Comment: post your index.html code

Comment: `<h1>Data</h1>
<br/>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name></th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>number</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>`

Comment: i left last `<td>` parts because i dont know how to call it to this form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="a", newname="s", number="d")
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="testdb")
        x = conn.cursor()
        x.execute("SELECT * FROM details")
        conn.commit()
        items = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in items:
            print row[0], row[1]
        conn.rollback()
        conn.close()
        return render.index(items)
```

Run this code and check output in terminal and let me know the data is comming or not

Comment: `__template__() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)` i got this errror.can you just tell me how to call these row values to index.html